# How can I customize comment block characters in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I created a language extension for Visual Studio Code and I would like to change the comment block characters, but I couldn't find a way to do so..

How can I do it?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

OK, I finally figured out what the problem was.
There are two ways you can change the comment blocks:

###### 1. Configuration file

I don’t know why it's not in the documentation (or at least I couldn't find it), but there is an optional property you pass to the object inside the `contributes.languages` array in the *package.json* file named **configuration**.

The description found on the Visual Studio Code source code:

> A relative path to a file containing configuration options for the
> language.

In those files you can create an object like this one and it's going to overwrite the default comment characters

```
{
  "comments": {
    "lineComment": "//",
    "blockComment": [ "<!--", "-->" ]
  }
}
```

You can see this properties on the API references: *[CommentRule](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api#CommentRule)*

Note: That comment block command is triggered with a different shortcut. You can overwrite it though (in a general or even for a specific language using the property `when` on the key binding object).

> ⇧⌥A - Toggle Block Comment - editor.action.blockComment

*[Key Bindings for Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/customization/keybindings)*

###### 2. "Syntax" file *.tmLanguage*

Yes, you can do it from there too and you can make it even better.
You can see an example on *[vscode-handlebars/syntaxes/handlebars.tmLanguage](https://github.com/andrejunges/vscode-handlebars/blob/master/syntaxes/handlebars.tmLanguage#L68)*.

Comment: Where ist this 'package.json' stored?

Comment: For me, the file was located (mac OS): /Users/USERNAME/.vscode/extensions/EXTENSION_NAME/language-configuration.json

Comment: How to get rid of the auto inserted asterisk in block comments?
I don't want any asterisks just /** .... */  Thank you.

Comment: What's the extension name for typescript?

Comment: @Meryan This is a good question, did you start a separate thread on it?

Comment: @oxwilder I believe I captured my frustration with these asterisks here 
Please pitch in your vote and insgihts

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70309428/how-can-i-configure-jsdoc-or-vscode-to-not-use-leading-star-asterix-in-block-com

Comment: For windows, the file is located at:
`C:\Users\USERNAME\.vscode\extensions\EXT_NAME`
It might also be at:
`C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions`

Comment: No joy on 27-Oct-2022 on Windows 10 Pro. I don't find any of these files or settings.

Answer (score 1):

try this extension: [`ArturoDent.custom-language-syntax`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69147985/7860292)

[I tested with `lineComment` for `[properties]` with v0.6.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69138666/how-to-change-the-comment-style-for-a-particular-language#comment136677066_69147985)

---

the configure reference: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/language-configuration-guide#comment-toggling , like:

> VS Code offers two commands for comment toggling. `Toggle Line Comment` and `Toggle Block Comment`. You can specify `comments.blockComment` and `comments.lineComment` to control how VS Code should comment out lines / blocks.

Answer (score -1):

Try deleting the [Babel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babel_(transcompiler)) extension if you are using the Visual Studio Code editor. It worked for me.