# VS Code, ColdFusion, comment shortcut produces wrong comment

Tags: coldfusion, comments, visual-studio-code

I write ColdFusion in VS code and have [KamasamaK's CF extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=KamasamaK.vscode-cfml) installed. When I am inside a `.cfc` file and when I hit shortcut key - <kbd>Ctrl-/</kbd> - it comments out code in a wrong fassion, like so:

```
// <cfset cfc = "wrong comment format" />
```

Now, I already followed instructions in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34822552/how-to-customize-comment-block-characters-in-visual-studio-code#answer-35788355) and have this written inside of my

`C:\Users\<username>\.vscode\extensions\kamasamak.vscode-cfml-0.5.3\language-configuration.json` file:

```
"comments": {
    "lineComment": "<!--- --->",
    "blockComment": [ "<!--- ", " --->" ]
}
```

and when I hit shortcut key inside of my `.cfm` file it works great:

```
<!--- <cfset cfm = "it works in cfm file" /> --->
```

but for some reason it does not work in `.cfc` file.

**Additional information:**

1. My `.cfc` file is recognized as ColdFusion file (I see `CFML` written in the bottom right corner of the VS Code).
2. When I close and reopen VS Code I see notification in the bottom right corner "Caching components". While this caching in progress commenting **does** work correctly and I was able to comment code out correctly like so:

```
<!--- // <cfset cfc = "wrong comment format" />  --->
```

however, after caching is done it is back to commenting out code in the wrong fashion, like so:

```
// <!--- // <cfset cfc = "wrong comment format" />  --->
```

3. I tested it with every single other extension disabled.

**Questions**:

- Anybody knows what could be wrong?
- Could this be a bug in the extension itself?

**Edit 1**.

Yesterday I left this comment:

> [...] I created basic component, 3 lines of code, and formatting worked! Thank you. Need to analyze my code now.

However, this morning I tried to create the exact same basic `.cfc` again but this time it did **not** work, unlike yesterday:

```
<component>
    // <cfset a = "a" />
</component>
```

Not sure what is going on, but since it works while "Caching components" pop-up is running I think the answer lies somewhere there.

**Edit 2**.

I just tried to create basic component for the 3rd time to test comment feature again. Immediately after I finished typing out this code

```
<component>
    <cfset a = "a" />
</component>
```

I hit comment shortcut key and commenting worked:

```
<component>
    <!--- <cfset a = "a" /> --->
</component>
```

However, after about 1 second later or less, I hit shortcut key again and it again commented out code wrongly:

```
<component>
    // <!--- <cfset a = "a" /> --->
</component>
```

I suspect that this new file got cached and correct `.cfc` commenting stopped working. So, it looks like there might be a bug in extension where cached components comment code in wrong fashion.

**Edit 3**.

I created [this issue in GitHub](https://github.com/KamasamaK/vscode-cfml/issues/60) based on my best understanding of the problem.

Comment: What does the code look like prior to the incorrect comment? I don't have that problem in my CFCs. But then I've seen the incorrect comment added generally due to the surrounding code having inconsistent formatting.

Comment: @AdrianJ.Moreno You are right! I created basic component, 3 lines of code, and formatting worked! Thank you. Need to analyze my code now.

Comment: But on the other hand, my code runs, so there should not be syntactical issues otherwise code would not run. I am not entirely sure what's going on, still.

Comment: Looks like there might be a bug in extension. I added edits.

Comment: I see other people at work who it works for but it has stopped working for me and I never get it to work.

Comment: Possibly related: https://github.com/ilich/vscode-coldfusion/issues/18