# How to change the comment style for a particular language

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am new to VScode.
I was wondering if there is any way to change the behavior of the `line comment` shortcut key for a particular file extension.
In particular, I have a file whose name is `file.frm`.
Now a line comment for this file type should be `*` i.e.

```
 cat file.frm
 * This is a comment
 // This is not a comment
 // However ctrl+k ctrl+c puts line comment as // like in C
```

The default `ctrl+k ctrl+c` puts line comment as `//` similar to `C`.
I want to change this to `*`. But of course, the behavior of this shortcut will be unchanged for other file types as usual. How do I do it?

There is official extension support for syntax highlighting for this file-type but apparently no support for line comment shortcut:

```
Name: FORM Syntax Highlighting
Id: benruijl0774.vscode-form
Description: Syntax highlighting for the symbolic manipulation toolkit FORM.
Version: 0.0.1
Publisher: Ben Ruijl
VS Marketplace Link: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items? 
itemName=benruijl0774.vscode-form
```

Comment: if you have language support the language definition should define the comment characters, if not file a bug request at there repo

Comment: Well, I find their git page and I see there in `language-configuration.json` the line comment is there as `//`. Can I change that? If so where do I find that file in my vscode?

Comment: in the extension folder in your user/home directory `.vscode` folder, search the VSC doc for extensions location for your OS, or you can make a local repo copy, change the file and package it and install it from the extensions bar top menu, Ben is still active on github so it might not take long for him to fix this

Comment: Yes. This is the place. `~/.vscode/extensions/benruijl0774.vscode-form-0.0.1` where I found `language-configuration.json`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I made an extension that makes this process easier: [Custom Language Properties](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.custom-language-syntax).

1. Have a file of the language open that you want to change the comment or bracket style.
2. Run the following command from the Command Palette:

```
"Show the language configuration file for the current editor"
"command": "custom-language-syntax.showConfigFile",
```

3. That will open an editor with the `language-configuration.json` file that pertains to the language ID of the active text editor.  It will look similar to this:

```
{
  "comments": {
    "lineComment": "//",  // this is wwrong
      "blockComment": [
        "/*",
        "*/"
    ]
}, 
// <etc.>
```

4. Now you have two options:

- Option A:  Change the  `lineComment` value to:

```
"lineComment": "*",
```

That changes the actual file within the language extension you installed.  **Reload vscode** to see it take effect.

The downside to this option is that if the `language-configuration.json` file is ever updated by the extension author in the future you will lose your changes and have to re-edit the file.  [In the case of the `form` language, it doesn't seem likely that that will happen very often.]  In any case, the `Custom Language Properties` command makes it easy to view and change that file.

- Option B:  Run the following command from the Command Palette with the language configuration file as the active editor:

```
"Transform the current language configuration file for intellisense"
```

This will make the following steps easier as you should get intellisense in your settings.

5. In your `settings.json`:

```
"custom-language-properties": {
  "form.comments.lineComment": "*"  // you should get intellisense for most of this
}
```

This will not change the underlying `language-configuration.json` file, just override its `lineComment` entry.  You do not need to reload vscode to see this setting take effect.

---

[image: Changing a language comment style demo]

In your case, if you run step 4(b) this extension will not be able to set the language ID itself to the unusual extensionID of some languages like `form`.  In that case an input box will appear for you to input the language identifier (as it appears in the lower right corner of the vscode window for those file types).  In your case, enter 'form', <kbd>Enter</kbd> to confirm and you should be all set.

Comment: could this extension support built-in supporting language ? like `[properties]` (sadly the default comment char of which was changed to be '`;`' instead of '`#`' sometime ...

Comment: @laoyb Yes, I believe so - I didn't know `properties` was a language.  What is the typical file extension for a `properties` file?  By the way, when I change a file`s language mode to `properties` and toggle a line comment, I do get a `#`.    Can you explain why you are getting a `;` - do you have an extension that is doing that?

Comment: @laoyb I added support to v0.6.2 - make sure you have that version.  And you should first run the command `Custom Language Properties: Check for new language extensions` so that the extension will look for the `properties` language configuration file and build what it needs to work.  Please let me know if it works for you.  Thanks.

Comment: a little strangely ... after exit and launch the latest flatpak version 1.84.1, the line comment works fine with `#` ... (PS: what I tried yesterday was under a 1.82.x instance

Comment: now I tested in a win10 1.76.2 instance which was just launched hours ago, indeed a `;` (seems that the max supported version of your extension under this vscode version is only v0.5.4); then I upgrade vscode to 1.84.2 and the `#` back ...

Comment: tested `ArturoDent.custom-language-syntax` v0.6.3 in a win10 1.84.2 vscode instance: the command `Custom Language Properties: Check for new language extensions` seems do nothing foreground ? however the command `Custom Language Properties: Show language configuration for current editor` then opened a file `C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions\ini\properties.language-configuration.json`, and modification on the `comments`.`lineComment` attribute of which works~ (thx for your work~

Comment: comfirmed the v0.6.3 works for `[properties]` ~

Comment: @laoyb The better option would be to make the setting change rather than editing the language configuration file that you opened.  Both methods work, but if that configuration file is updated you will have to modify it again.

Answer (score 0):

CTRL + SHIFT + P

Change language mode

"Configure 'Ini' language based settings..."

or with mouse like on screenshot [image])

then in this settings.json file add the following lines after the existing ones:

```
"[ini]": {
    "editor.comments.insertSpace": true,
    "editor.comments.ignoreEmptyLines": true,
    "editor.comments.prepend": ";"
}
```

prepend - not highlighted, but it works

Comment: seems not work for '`#`' for `[properties]` ...