# How can I configure JSDoc or VSCode to NOT use leading star/asterix in block comments

Tags: jsdoc

I find the leading star/asterix very annoying,
the moment I press EnterKey inside a block comment a leading star is inserted.

I would like my block comments to simply look like this

[image]

I do not see any specific jsdoc extension in my installed ones, let me know if I need one.

[image]

If it a configuration I am missing please let me know which file/settings I need to change.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't.

- [Despite disabling JSDoc autocompletion, VSCode still completes doc comments](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/139983)
- [completeJSDocs: false does not fully disable autocompletion](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/98143)

However, the leading `*` is not auto inserted once you have a non `*` line.

Ex:

```js
/**     ENTER HERE WILL INSERT A ASTERISK
    a   ENTER HERE WILL NOT 
     
 */
```

Comment: Thank you for providing some insights on this, however I will not accept it as answer but let it testify of the stupidity of VSCode / JSDoc thinking this is a feature request :(
If VSCode wanted 20 upvotes in 60 days, totally absurd, as I have had this browser tab open since the original post and it will remain as such :)