# vscode - Language specific comment block characters (so that #region can be recognized for folding)

Tags: visual-studio-code, coldfusion, comments

I work with ColdFusion in vscode with KamasamaK's CFML extension. In CF comment block is similar to HTML except it has additional 3rd `-`, like so:

```
<!--- comment --->
```

I want to take advantage of vscode recognizing `#region [...] #endregion` declarations to fold regions of my code. HTML comments work perfectly fine:

[image]

**How can I make vscode `#region` work with CF comments?**

---

I found [this SO Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34822552/how-can-i-customize-comment-block-characters-in-visual-studio-code) (which also led me to [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/language-configuration-guide) and [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/contribution-points#contributes.languages) pieces of documentation) but as far as I understood this is for when you build your own extensions. Quote from the top of [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/contribution-points) page:

> Contribution Points are a set of JSON declarations that you make in the contributes field of the package.json Extension Manifest.

But I'm not building no extensions here, I just want to let vscode know that `<!---` is a comment so that it recognizes `#region`.

Comment: Someone referenced this post in an Issue with that CFML extension's repository. I was going to suggest you do exactly that. https://github.com/KamasamaK/vscode-cfml/issues/84

Comment: @AdrianJ.Moreno That was me :)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, that is something that Microsoft built into the HTML extension that Adobe has not built into the ColdFusion extension.

It might be possible for you to add it yourself, but since you say you're not an extension builder it will likely require that you ask Adobe to add that functionality if you want to see it implemented.

Comment: I see, thank you. For the record, I don't use Adobe's CF extension. I use KamasamaK's CFML extension. I updated my question with this info.

Comment: Ah yes, then you will need to reach out to KamasamaK.